# Old Ubuntu core snap versions are filling up disk space

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 with `snapd` and the basic `core` snap installed since it was released.
After some time I observed that the `/snap/core` directory fills up with multiple older versions.
To remove them I'll have to execute `sudo snap remove core --revision <number>` manually.

[Multiple versions of snaps & garbage collection](https://snapcraft.io/docs/core/versions) section in 
[Snaps and snapcraft documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/) explains that after every update of a snap package the current version and the one before are installed and older versions are getting automatically removed (just as it was earlier the case).

As I cannot find further information in `snap help`, I am asking whether there is a setting or a switch command in `snapd` to enable automatic removal of those older `core` snap packages.
Additional information : What I described is valid for 3 machines with the same configuration.

Comment: The default in snapd is to keep 3 versions, current and two previous. How many were you seeing?

Comment: Thanks for this information @popey ! Whenever I found more than two `core` versions, I uninstalled the oldest one manually and in most cases I saw three installed versions, but I am not sure if I also found four versions before. Why does the documentation provide a different information ? Can I change the default settings to keep only the current and the one before ? Maybe you can explain it by writing an answer ? :)

Comment: If you're seeing more than 3 then it's a bug in my mind, so I'd file it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd . Would need to see the output of "snap changes" and show directory listing maybe in /snap/<appname> to show multiple installed versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now I don't believe it's possible to change the number of old versions of any snap, that's set at 3. If you see more than that, it's likely a bug, so should be filed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd

Answer (score 10):

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/1310825/how-to-remove-old-version-of-installed-snaps) lists several solutions for older snap version removing:

[Manual script by popey](https://superuser.com/a/1330590) to delete "all old versions of snaps"

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # https://superuser.com/a/1330590
> # Removes old revisions of snaps
> # CLOSE ALL SNAPS BEFORE RUNNING THIS set -eu
>
> snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
>     while read snapname revision; do
>         snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
>     done
> ```

And "snap set system refresh.retain" setting for "snap 2.34 and later" [by Mustapha Hadid](https://superuser.com/a/1361201) to store only 2 revisions of every snap:

> ```
> $ sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2
> ```
>
> The refresh.retain value can only be a number between 2 and 20 and has
>   a default value of 3

Comment: i've run that sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2 , but there are still three copies of some snaps, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

use a command like this :-

```
sudo snap remove chromium       --revision 1461
```

where

```
chromium = example software
1461 = example revision
```

you can use "mount | grep snap" to find versions

or

```
snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}'
```

for old versions