# root folder is just filling up and filling up

Tags: partitioning, directory, root

I looked at other threads on this and they suggested some useful stop-gap things to free up space in the file *[uninstalling programs i wasn't using or almost never used, making my root bigger.]*

**Why does the folder keep filling up** (even though I'm not installing anything) **and is there a way to stop it?** It never happened before even when i'd had the same Ubuntu install for years, and this is new

Here's a screenshot of the message I'm getting in case I haven't explained it right:

https://postimg.cc/xqcnr2sq

```
user@computername:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  1.9M  783M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        14G   13G  804M  94% /
tmpfs           3.9G  185M  3.7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/81
/dev/loop1      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77
/dev/loop3      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop2       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop4       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop5      144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop6      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop10     4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop7       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop8      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gimp/130
/dev/loop9      196M  196M     0 100% /snap/vlc/555
/dev/loop11      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop12      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/254
/dev/loop14     152M  152M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40
/dev/loop15     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/loop13      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop17     4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop16     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop18     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/770
/dev/loop19      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop20     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop21     518M  518M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/115
/dev/loop22     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop23     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gimp/165
/dev/loop24     161M  161M     0 100% /snap/midori/451
/dev/loop25     484M  484M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/106
/dev/loop26      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop27     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/loop28      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/731
/dev/loop29      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop31     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/768
/dev/loop30      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop32      36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop33      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/258
/dev/loop34     523M  523M     0 100% /snap/libreoffice/112
/dev/sda6       101G   75G   22G  78% /home
tmpfs           785M   48K  784M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you used `du` (disk usage) to explore where the disk space is being used?  If you have some program/job monitor something & write log files when a specific condition occurs and it's not a common event (hence lots of reporting where it used to be minimal). Do you `apt autoremove` or `apt autoclean` often?  What size is it? (smaller than the 25gb recommended? which I find small, but I know others think is large - ie. your use dictates if it's small/plenty..)

Comment: it's 15 gigabites, which i know isn't a lot but it's a small SSD drive https://postimg.cc/8fzzrfDS < here's the DU, is there any issue that stands out? is the problem just that my root is so small and when it's this size there will always be problems?

Comment: Sometimes (assuming `/var` isn't a separate filesystem) it's a result of logs run wild: see for example [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/a/515152/178692)

Comment: the logrotate thing is present but i don't know how to check to see how often it is running, if at all, i couldn't follow the instructions... I noticed the snaps folder is huge so I followed the instructions here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-remove-old-snap-versions-to-free.html to limit its size, won't know if that has worked for a while though

Comment: open up a terminal and update your question with output of running   df -h ... to copy terminal text highlight then control-shift-c to copy then paste into question

Comment: uff i thought maybe i'd sorted it, since it was stable for a while, but now today there is even less space. when it fills up i have to use safemode or i can't boot up, and i have already uninstalled everything i don't use :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by getting rid of snapd completely.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

(Special thanks to OldFred on the Ubuntu Forum for this suggestion)

Comment: Because I always do a complete reinstall when I upgrade rather than doing it from within the OS, when I upgraded to focal fossa I decided to just put / and / home on the one partition to avoid having to get rid of snapd (as it is getting more and more integrated into the OS and harder to live without). This is not a good idea if you plan to upgrade through the OS. I also limited the number of back up snaps in line with advice from osgs here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/895634/old-ubuntu-core-snap-versions-are-filling-up-disk-space