# Why do I have two snapd and snap-store? Can I uninstall one?

Tags: 20.04, snap

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I noticed when I ran `df -h` that I have two `snapd`'s and `snap-store`'s. Can I uninstall one of them or will it uninstall both? Or is it really just that way? Here's what I mean:

```
/dev/loop1      234M  234M     0 100% /snap/atom/260
/dev/loop4       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/loop5       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop9       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop0      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1350
/dev/loop8      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop11      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop3       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10126
/dev/loop6      240M  240M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1328
/dev/loop12      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467 <--
/dev/loop13      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/481 <--
/dev/loop10     218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop2      235M  235M     0 100% /snap/atom/263
/dev/loop7      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop15      31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9607 <--
/dev/loop14      31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9279 <--
```

Comment: Snapcraft keeps at least 1 older version, so you can rollback. I think the default is 3, but can be toggled down to 2 with `snap set system refresh.retain=2` - also see here: [Old Ubuntu core snap versions are filling up disk space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895634/old-ubuntu-core-snap-versions-are-filling-up-disk-space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove snap-store without removing snapd](https://askubuntu.com/q/1193674/)